# How can I update a json file in ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

I want to do this in ruby.

Say I have an example.json file that looks like

```
{
   "name" : "My name is - "
}
```

and I want to update that to

```
{
   "name" : "My name is - Chris"
}
```

I know to do this

```
require 'json'
json = JSON.parse('example.json')
name = json['name'] + ' Chris'
```

Now how I write name back into example.json file and save the file, simply like this?

```
json['name'] = name
```

Comment: Have you at least tried the last bit of your question?

Comment: Author, did you even bother googling "ruby json"? Or testing the code you provided? Go read http://devdocs.io/ruby/json - If this doesn't answer all your questions I'll gladly help or provide examples.